# Node package dependencies for application

Tags: meteor, npm

As Meteor 0.6.x introduced support of node packages, it is still not clear how to configure dependency to npm package for whole application. Lets say i need to 'require' some node package in the server code. How to make sure this package will be installed after app is deployed somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

It's easy enough to setup a `package.json` file in the root of your project.

You can find a cheatsheet here to help you set one up: http://package.json.nodejitsu.com/

Under dependencies you can specify your runtime deps. 
They are installed using the `$ npm install` command or `# npm -g install` in case you wnat to install them on your system rather than local to the project.